# How to compare multidimensional arrays in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

Suppose `A` and `B` are multidimensional arrays. The number and size of dimensions are unknown apriori.

How to compare both the number of dimensions and corresponding elements to ensure they are equal (or close for double values)?

Answer (score 5):

For **strict** equality of values (and of course of dimensions), use [`isequal`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html):

> `isequal(A,B)` returns logical `1` (`true`) if `A` and `B` are the same size and their contents are of equal value; otherwise, it returns logical `0` (`false`).

Example:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4];
>> B = [10 20 30];
>> equal = isequal(A,B)
equal =
     0
```

Equivalently, you can evaluate the three conditions:

1. same number of dimensions,
2. same size along each dimension, and
3. same values for all entries

with [short-circuit "and"](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html), so that each condition is only evaluated if the preceding one is met:

```
equal = ndims(A)==ndims(B) && all(size(A)==size(B)) && all(A(:)==B(:));
```

This allows generalizing the last condition to test for **close enough** values:

```
tol = 1e-6;
equal = ndims(A)==ndims(B) && all(size(A)==size(B)) && all(abs(A(:)-B(:))<tol);
```

Comment: I didn't know about isequal, which is quite cool. This is a more complete answer than mine below.

Comment: I prefer `isequaln` to `isequal`, as I like NaN==NaN to evaluate to `true`

Answer (score 2):

I would compare the dimensions first:

```
assert(ndims(A) == ndims(B), 'Dimensions are not the same');
```

then the sizes

```
assert(all(size(A) == size(B)), 'Sizes are not the same');
```

and then compare the elements

```
assert(all(A(:) == B(:)), 'Some elements are not the same');
```

If you're looking to compare for "closeness", then you could do

```
assert(all(abs(A(:) - B(:)) < thr), 'Some elements are not close');
```

for some threshold thr of closeness.

Answer (score 1):

To compare the sizes, you can compare the output of the `size` function.  Then, once you know the sizes are the same, you can compare the matrices directly...by first turning them into a 1-D vector so that you only need one `all` command.  Something like

```
if (ndims(A) == ndims(B))
    disp('They have the same number of dimensions!');    
    if all(size(A) == size(B))
        disp('They are the same size!']);
        if all(A(:) == B(:))
            disp(['They hold the same values!']);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: if they have different number of dimensions, your first  check is going to throw an error...

Comment: Good point.  I edited my example code to add the extra check.